# How to make first level of MultiIndex as the columns?

Tags: pandas

Say I have a MultiIndex dataframe like:

```
In [1]: arrays = [['one','one','one','two','two','two'],[1,2,3,1,2,3]]      

In [2]: df = pa.DataFrame(randn(6,1),index=pa.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(*arrays)),columns=['A'])

In [3]: df                                                                  
Out[3]:                                                                     
              A                                                             
one 1  0.229037                                                             
    2 -1.640695                                                             
    3  0.908127                                                             
two 1 -0.918750                                                             
    2  1.170112                                                             
    3 -2.620850
```

I would like to change this to a new dataframe, with the columns as the first level index of the MultiIndex dataframe? Is there an easy way? (below an example)

```
In [12]: dft = df.ix['one']                                                 

In [13]: dft = dft.rename(columns={'A':'one'})                              

In [14]: dft['two'] = df.ix['two']['A']                                     

In [15]: dft                                                                
Out[15]:                                                                    
        one       two                                                       
1  0.229037 -0.918750                                                       
2 -1.640695  1.170112                                                       
3  0.908127 -2.620850
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for [pandas.unstack](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
In [56]: df
Out[56]: 
              A
one 1  0.229037
    2 -1.640695
    3  0.908127
two 1 -0.918750
    2  1.170112
    3 -2.620850

In [57]: df.unstack(level=0)
Out[57]: 
          A          
        one       two
1  0.229037 -0.918750
2 -1.640695  1.170112
3  0.908127 -2.620850
```

Comment: Thanks! this is quite useful, I guess it's in the development version.

Comment: No, I'm wrong. it's at least in the 0.9 version which I am using now.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add something to this, there is another option of making a multi-index into columns using the `reset_index()` function. The difference here being that it simply "pops" out the values as new columns. Depends on your usecase:

```
In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
              A
one 1 -1.598591
    2 -0.354813
    3 -0.435924
two 1  1.408328
    2  0.448303
    3  0.381360

In [6]: df.reset_index()
Out[6]: 
  level_0  level_1         A
0     one        1 -1.598591
1     one        2 -0.354813
2     one        3 -0.435924
3     two        1  1.408328
4     two        2  0.448303
5     two        3  0.381360
```